# COm server accessing the application

Tags: mfc

I have written a simple dialog based MFC application using a thirdd party soft tree control. I am trying to write a automation client for the application. For this I wrote a singleton out-of-process COM Testing Agent for the dialog based application sample app. The Com server exposes a Run method to the automation client. This Run method access the gut of the mfc app and actually mimicks a click on the GUI. The problem i am facing is when the automation client tries to invoke Run method on the Com object it is able to invioke it but when the Run method crashes when it tries to access the control's methods such as getCaretInedx.

I have tried to cach the exception and log the message to a file but have not been able to do so.

My question is: Is there any limitation in the way a com object can access the application? Or am i missing anything to facilitate this.

Any help or pointer is greatly appreciated. Since this is my first in COM I have not been able to make much progress.

Thanks

Comment: What does the debugger say? You can use multi application debugging... where is the code location? What is on the call stack?

Answer (score 0):

Is your client's window actually being created? If not, the hwnd doesn't exist, which is probably why it crashes. Furthermore, your client may be hidden behind another window when it is started, and may exhibit different behavior than when the user called it through regular interaction.

In general, calling code that relies on or interacts with the UI from a COM server is fraught with peril, especially when that code is not written in the first place to behave like this. Most UI isn't that defensive about HWND's existing etc.